# Can multiple WebClient interfere with each other?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, web-services

I must build a Application that will use Webclient multiple times to retrieve every "t" seconds information from a server.

Here is a small plan to show you what I'm doing in my application:

1. Connect to the Web Client "USER_LOGIN" that returns me a GUID(user unique ID). I save it and keep it to use it in future Web Client calls.
2. Connect to the Web Client "USER_GETINFO" using the GUID I saved before as parameter. This Web Service returns an array of strings holding all my personal user information( my Name, Age, Email, etc...). => I save the array information this way: Textblock.Text = e.Result[2].
3. Starting a Dispatcher.Timer with a 2 seconds Tick to start my Loop. (Purpose of this is to retrieve information and update it every 2 seconds)
4. Connect to the Web Client "USER GETFRIEND", wich is in my Timer, giving him the GUID as parameter. It returns me an array filled with my friends informations(Name, email, message, etc...). I inserted this WebClient in the timer so my friend list refreshes every 2 seconds.

I am able to create all the steps without any error until step 3. When I call the "USER_GETFRIEND" Web Client I am facing two major problems:

- On one side I noticed that my number of Thread increased dramatically. => I always thought that when a WebClient had finished its instructions it would shut down by itself, but apparently that does not happen in Asyncronous calls.
- And on the other side I was surprised to see that using the same proxy for two Webclient calls(ie: if i declare test.MainSoapClient proxy = new test.MainSoapClient()), the data i would retrieve from "USER_GETFRIEND" e.Result, was sent directly to my "USER_GETINFO" array. And so my Name and Email adresses on the UI were replaced by the same value in the USER_GETFRIEND array. So my Name is changed to my friends email and so on...

I would like to know if it's possible to close a WebClient call(or Thread) that I am not using anymore to prevent any conflicts? Or if someone has any suggestion concerning my code and the way i should develop my application please feel free to propose.

Comment: What do you mean by "WebClient"?

Comment: Just for info: I am programming in c# in Silverlight 4.

What I mean by WebClient is to consume a WebService. When you do that in Silverlight it has to be in Asynchronous mode and contained into an EventHandler.

Comment: @John Saunders: Likely this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: I have already read the whole MSDN documentation but nothing has to do with my problem.

Comment: @dtb: i thought not. He's talking about "web client" like one would talk about a proxy class from "Add Service Reference".

Comment: @Ephis: can you please show some code so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes sorry I am not clear in my explanation(i'm not a native english speaker). I am talking like dtb said about a proxy class that I added from "Add Service Reference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer a few weeks ago and figured out it was important to answer my own question.

My whole problem was that I wasn't unsubscribing from my asynchronous calls and that I was using the same proxy class from "Add Service reference":

So when I was using:

```
proxy.webservice += new Eventhandler<whateverinhere>(my_method);
```

I never did:

```
proxy.webservice -= new Eventhandler<whateverinhere>(my_method);
```

Hope it will help someone.